# Using date parameter in SQL Server CTE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, parameters

I'm trying to use a start and end date parameter in a T-SQL common table expression. I'm very new to SQL Server development and I'm unsure of what I'm missing in the query.

I can specify values for `@startdate` & `@enddate` and get correct results.

However, I'm trying to figure out how to make the two parameters open so a user can specify start and end date values. The query will be used in an SSRS report.

```
DECLARE @startdate Datetime,
        @enddate Datetime;

SET @startdate = '2017-02-09';
SET @enddate = '2017-02-10';

WITH ManHours AS 
( 
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        a.plant_name AS Plant, SUM(tc.total_hr) AS TotalHours
    FROM 
        area AS a 
    INNER JOIN 
        tf_department AS dep ON a.plant_id = dep.plant_id 
    INNER JOIN 
        tf_timecard AS tc ON dep.department_id = tc.department_id
    WHERE 
        tc.timecard_dt BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
        AND tc.department_id IN (266, 453, ...endlessly long list of IDs......)
        AND tc.hourtype_id = 1
    GROUP BY 
        a.plant_name),
Tonnage AS 
( 
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        a.plant_name AS Plant, SUM(tglt.postqty) AS TotalTonnage
    FROM 
        area AS a 
    INNER JOIN 
        plantgl AS pgl ON a.plant_id = pgl.plant_id 
    INNER JOIN 
        tgltransaction AS tglt ON pgl.glacckey = tglt.glacctkey
    WHERE 
        tglt.postdate BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
    GROUP BY 
        a.plant_name
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ManHours.Plant, 
    SUM(TotalTonnage) as 'Production Tons' , 
    SUM(TotalHours) as 'Man Hours', 
    TotalTonnage / TotalHours AS TonsPerManHour
FROM 
    ManHours 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    Tonnage ON ManHours.Plant = tonnage.Plant
GROUP BY 
    ManHours.Plant, ManHours.TotalHours, Tonnage.TotalTonnage
```

Comment: wrap this query in a stored procedure

Comment: You can just remove the DECLARE and SET statements. When you put the rest of the query into an dataset in SSRS, it will create the two parameters automatically. You just need to change the parameters to a DATE type and it will prompt to enter the dates before it runs the query.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of a stored procedure you could use. In addition, I provided two alternatives to the "endlessly long list of IDs" that is specified in the CTE. In my opinion, it is optimal to pull this logic out of the query and place it at the beginning of the stored procedure. This will enable you, or others, to easily go back and modify this list *if / when* it changes. Even better, I provided a TABLE VARIABLE (@ListOfDeptIdsFromTable) that you can use to actually *retrieve* this data as opposed to hard-coding a string.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Report
    @startdate DATETIME,
    @enddate DATETIME
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @ListOfDeptIds VARCHAR(MAX) = '266, 453, ...endlessly long list of IDs......';

    DECLARE @ListOfDeptIdsFromTable TABLE
    (
        department_id INT
    )

    INSERT INTO @ListOfDeptIdsFromTable (department_id)
    SELECT department_id
    FROM -- Table here
    WHERE -- Where credentials to retrieve the long list

    WITH ManHours AS 
    ( 
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            a.plant_name AS Plant, SUM(tc.total_hr) AS TotalHours
        FROM 
            area AS a 
        INNER JOIN 
            tf_department AS dep ON a.plant_id = dep.plant_id 
        INNER JOIN 
            tf_timecard AS tc ON dep.department_id = tc.department_id
        WHERE 
            tc.timecard_dt BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
            AND tc.department_id IN (@ListOfDeptIds) -- or ... IN (SELECT department_id FROM @ListOfDeptIdsFromTable)
            AND tc.hourtype_id = 1
        GROUP BY 
            a.plant_name),
    Tonnage AS 
    ( 
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            a.plant_name AS Plant, SUM(tglt.postqty) AS TotalTonnage
        FROM 
            area AS a 
        INNER JOIN 
            plantgl AS pgl ON a.plant_id = pgl.plant_id 
        INNER JOIN 
            tgltransaction AS tglt ON pgl.glacckey = tglt.glacctkey
        WHERE 
            tglt.postdate BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
        GROUP BY 
            a.plant_name
    )
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        ManHours.Plant, 
        SUM(TotalTonnage) as 'Production Tons' , 
        SUM(TotalHours) as 'Man Hours', 
        TotalTonnage / TotalHours AS TonsPerManHour
    FROM 
        ManHours 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        Tonnage ON ManHours.Plant = tonnage.Plant
    GROUP BY 
        ManHours.Plant, ManHours.TotalHours, Tonnage.TotalTonnage

END
GO
```